# Assigning MAC addresses from unbought oui

Tags: ethernet, mac-address

I'm a freelancer. I have finished a project for a company that uses Ethernet (TCP+UDP) with a STM32F4 Device.

While I was testing I used MACs  in the space 00:00:00:00:00:xx , but now we need to assign final MACs.

The question here is that the company that pays the project dont want to buy OUI mac space. They say that is it practically impossible to have 2 cards in the same network with the same MAC address.

Another reason that they are telling me is that they will use this ethernet device card in places where no more ethernet device except a WIFI router and maybe more of our cards would be connected.

I found on internet places telling that you can use FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF as null mac address, I have been testing it without any problem (i thought that ARP would fail but it is working), but they would not be able to connnect 2 cards together in this case.

I have some questions about this.

- Is it legal to use MACs from other companies or even non assigned MACs addresses?
- Is there any interval of MACs that they can use freely without paying

Any reason to convince them to buy the OUI space would be welcomed too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think using non-asigned OUI is good, but MAC addresses with second bit 1 are called "locally administered addresses" and can be used without registering to IEEE.

This mean that you can use MAC addresses like `x2:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx`, `x6:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx`, etc. to stand for your NIC.

Notr that MAC addresses with first bit 1 are for multicasting, not for standing fir single NIC, and that MAC address `FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF` is for broadcasting, not null.

[MAC address - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address)

Comment: Thanks for your help, probably they will use the "locally administered addresses".

Answer (score 0):

To clarify MikeCAT's answer - it is the two least significant bits of the 1st byte of the MAC address that are important - what I think of as the 7th and 8th bit:

??????XY:????????:????????  ????????:????????:????????

where ? represents any bit in the mac address, and X is the U/L bit and Y is the Uni/multi cast bit

If the the eighth bit of a MAC address is 1, devices may have trouble getting IP addresses using DHCP. If the eighth bit of a MAC address is 0, you may have more luck.

The 7th and 8th bit of MAC addresses are special:
Bit 8 == 0 for unicast
Bit 8 == 1 for multicast

Bit 7 is also special - 0 = globally unique (assigned to a manufacturer to use) and 1 = locally administered (we should use these addresses!)